# Compare the files with key/ID node and generate the output if difference are in Sibling nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

I want to compare the XML nodes (Key/ID node), and they see if the their sibling node has any different value, then fetch in output.

Input XML where two XML files are merged

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aggregatedData>
    **<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:report">
        <wd:test>
            <wd:CID>0011</wd:CID>
            <wd:name>Test10</wd:name>
            <wd:tag>TAG1<<wd:tag>
        </wd:test>
        <wd:test>
            <wd:CID>20012</wd:CID>
            <wd:name>Test12</wd:name>
  <wd:tag>TAG3<<wd:tag>
        </wd:test>
        <wd:test>
            <wd:CID>0014</wd:CID>
            <wd:name>Test14</wd:name>
  <wd:tag>TAG1<<wd:tag>
        </wd:test>
    </wd:Report_Data>**

   * <File xmlns="urn:ExternalSource">
        
        <Root1>
            <CID>0011</CID>
            <curre>INR</curre>
            <name>Test1200</name>
        </Root1>
         <Root1>
            <CID>0000</CID>
            <curre>cnd</curre>
            <name>Test00</name>
        </Root1>
        <Root1>
            <CID>20012</CID>
            <curre>INR</curre>
            <name>Test12</name>
        </Root1>
        <Root1>
            <CID>0010</CID>
            <curre>INR</curre>
            <name>why10</name>
        </Root1>
    </File>*
    
</aggregatedData>
```

Now in the above input file if compare the nodes only "0011" and "20012" are common but sibling  is different in only for "0011".

for 20012(File/Root1/CID and wd:Report_Data/wd:test/wd:CID), subling  node value are same in both place. it should not be picked.

for 0011 (File/Root1/CID and wd:Report_Data/wd:test/wd:CID), subling  node value are diffrent in both places hence below will be the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FinalFile>
       <Root1>
            <CID>0011</CID>
            <curre>INR</curre>
            <name>Test1200</name>
  <wd:tag>TAG1<<wd:tag>
        </Root1>
<FinalFile>
```

Tried to use XSLT2.0 and 30 using xsl:accumulator but no luck.

Please anyone can help me here. Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear which sibling node you are looking at, preceding ones and/or following ones, only the first preceding and/or following one? So you need to explain the requirement better and perhaps show us your code that doesn't work but perhaps gives us a better idea as to which nodes you want to compare.

Answer (score 1):

The logic you describe is not entirely clear. It seems you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:report"
xmlns:es="urn:ExternalSource"
exclude-result-prefixes="wd es">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="a"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="es:Root1" use="es:CID" />

<xsl:template match="/aggregatedData">
    <FinalFile>
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:test">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', wd:CID)[es:name != current()/wd:name]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </FinalFile>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result keeps the selected nodes in their original namespace. If that's not what you want, then further processing will be required. But first I wanted to make sure that the selecting logic is correct.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your response... need input  - If I want to fetch the nodes from both files or sections(<wd:Report_Data>) how I can fetch it

Comment: HI @michael. Updated the input and desire  output file, request you to please share your input.. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @Awanish If you understand the logic of my answer, you should be able to make the necessary adjustments yourself.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your response. Please assist me with the code logic.  I tried, but for some reason, my change is not functioning. Your suggestions will be much appreciated! I will be grateful. Thank you!